# simple joins between 2 mysql tables returning all results every time.. Help!

Tags: mysql, join

I just imported a large amount of data into two tables. Let's call them shipments and returns.

When trying to do a simple join (left or inner) based on any criteria in these two tables. query looks like it tries to do a cross join or find every combination instead of what the query should be pulling.

each table has an PK id field, but there is not FK relationship between the two other than some shared field.

I'm currently just trying to related them on shipment_id.

I feel this is a simple answer. Am I missing a reference or something obvious that is causing this? Thanks!

here's an example. This should returned under 100 rows. This instead returns hundreds of thousands.

```
SELECT r.*

FROM returns as r

left outer join shipments as s

on r.shipment_id = s.shipment_id

where r.date = '2011-06-20'
```

Comment: Can you post the two table structures and the query you have?

Comment: And a few rows of data from the 2 tables.

Comment: You don't have an `ON`clause that binds `returns` to `shipments`. This means that for every row in `returns`, you return ALL of the rows in `shipments`. That is, returns * shipments number of rows.

Comment: @JoshG: Add the structure of the 2 tables, please, in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be very simple, just not readily apparent until going through all the columns. It turns out that the shipment ID was duplicated through every row as it hit the upper limit for the int datatype. This is why joins were returning every record.

After switching the datatype to bigint and reimporting, everything worked great. Thanks all for looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that should work:

```
SELECT T0.*, T1.*
FROM shipments AS T0 LEFT JOIN returns AS T1 ON T0.shipment_id = T1.shipment_id
ORDER BY T0.shipment_id;
```

This query join assumes 1:1 on the shipment_id

It would be nice if you included the query you were using

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. that should return about 2800 rows, instead it returns hundreds of thousands.

Comment: This should work. otherwise you are doing something wrong. I'm guessing `shipment_id` is on `returns`, and relates to `id` on shipment. Hence, T0.id = T1.shipment_id

Comment: in this case shipment_id in both tables relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Josh,

I would be interested in seeing what would happen if you forced a join to a specific record or set of records instead of the whole table.  Assuming there is a shipment with an id of 5 in your table, you could try:

```
    SELECT r.* FROM returns as r
        left join shipments as s 
        ON 5 = r.shipment_id
        WHERE r.date = '2011-06-20'
```

While just a fancy where clause, it would at least prove that the join you are attempting will eventually work correctly.  The issue is that your on clause is always returning true, no matter what the value is.  This could be because it's not interpreting the shipment_id as an integer, but instead as a true/false variable where any value evaluates to true.

**Original Rejected Solution:**

No Foreign Key relationship should be needed in order to make the joins happen.  The PK id fields I'm assuming are an integer (or number, or whatever your rdms equivalent is)?

Can you past a snippet of your sql query?

**Updating based on posted query:**

I would add your explicit join criteria in order to rule out any funny business (my guess is since no criteria is specified, it's using 1=1, which always joins).  So I would change your query to look like:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM returns as r
left join shipments as s ON
s.ShipId = R.ReturnId
where r.date = '2011-06-20'
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: here's an example. This should returned under 100 rows. I have no idea what's causing this.


SELECT r.*

FROM returns as r

left outer join shipments as s

where r.date = '2011-06-20'

Comment: Josh, what is your DBMS system? Also, add an explicit on statement, as in "left outer join shipments as S on S.shipId = R.returnId

Comment: it's mysql. the on condition is there now, I had just forgot to paste it in.

Comment: The only reason I asked about the RDBMS is that not all require the "left outer join" syntax, but instead can use just "left join" and the outer is implied.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear. It's not working, I just meant I hadn't pasted it in to the post :) I know all about sql joining, so this makes no sense to me. I used the full syntax to make it clear what I was doing.

Comment: Ok.  And the shipment_id column is in fact an integer in both of the tables?

Comment: A simple test would be to join on a specific value and see if you get the result you expect, such as S.shipment_id = 5.

Comment: --Housekeeping:          Cleaned up my post above so I can take some of my answers up there instead of in comments?

Comment: Hey J Jones, thanks for your help. I finally figured out that the data source itself was corrupted, and all the shipment_ids were the same. Surprised I didn't notice it earlier. whenever anything is compared to shipment_id, EVERYTHING is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you are joining on, otherwise it will do a cartesian join:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM returns as r
LEFT JOIN shipments as s ON s.shipment_id = r.shipment_id
where r.date = '2011-06-20'
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. It doesn't matter what join I do, all results are returned. the query you link should return well under 100 results. Instead it returns hundreds of thousands. I tried yours and it's the same.

Comment: @JoshG - what do you mean "all results are returned"?  Do all the results have a date of '2011-06-20'?  If so, then this is still correct.  However, if you only want rows from the returns table that actually have a corresponding row in the shipments table, then you need to change the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: I think I just figured out the issue. It looks like for some reason the import into mysql duplicated the shipment_id for every single row, while all the other columns remained unique. I'm not sure how this happened as the source query to get the initial data doesn't do this. Thanks for looking into this!